# Javascript Google Maps API - Making markers clickable links

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm struggling through the Google maps API to create multiple markers with a link for each.  Being a javascript noob doesn't help either.

This is my code so far:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

```
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: -27.469703, lng: 153.025190}
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'X';

  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
  }

  var locations = [
    {lat: -27.449916, lng: 153.044031},
    {lat: -27.476536, lng: 153.020148},
  ]

</script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYHERE&callback=initMap">
```

The map displays fine and the markers are there, but everything I've tried to implement the links has been a fail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click listeners to each marker. See below:

```
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[i % labels.length]
    }); 

    marker.linkUrl = 'https://google.com';

    marker.addListener('click', function () {

        window.location = this.linkUrl;

    });

    return marker; 
});
```